# Twig version of php logic

Tags: php, for-loop, twig

I am trying to emulate some php locic in twig. I am not really from a php background so I am struggling a bit.

```
if ($arr = $caseStudy->getFilter_expertise()) {
   foreach ($arr as $key => $expertise  ) {
      $expertiseClass .=  '.'.$expertise;
   }
}
```

I have been looking at the twig docs and curently have this - which doesn't really do what I want.

```
{% if item.Filter_expertise %}
    {% for item in item.Filter_expertise|keys %}
        {% set expertiseClass = item %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh I got it

```
{% if item.Filter_expertise %}
    {% for item in item.Filter_expertise %}
        {% set expertiseClass = item %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```